# Can I output results of a MySQL query to a csv file via Putty?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mysql, putty, csv

I've typed the following code to output the csv file , but it shows an error

> mysql> SELECT *INFO OUTFILE 'd:/student.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
>   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FROM
>   tbl_student;

does anybody know what's wrong here?

Comment: PLease add the error that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *INFO
FROM tbl_student
INTO OUTFILE 'd:/student.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Keep in mind that the output file must not already exist and that the user MySQL is running as has write permissions to the directory MySQL is attempting to write the file to.